# How can I retrieve this dynamic object using Selenium and beautifulsoup for a web scraper?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm going a little crazy here. I don't know why I can't retrieve the course details from [this page](https://sa.ucla.edu/ro/Public/SOC/Results?t=19F&sBy=subject&sName=Computer%20Science%20%28COM%20SCI%29&subj=COM%20SCI&crsCatlg=Enter%20a%20Catalog%20Number%20or%20Class%20Title%20%28Optional%29&catlg=&cls_no=&btnIsInIndex=btn_inIndex) I'm trying to scrape. I am wondering how I can retrieve the course details, specifically time and day information so that I can add it to a dataframe, just as I did with the course titles. The course details are dynamic and only appear when the course title is expanded, this is why I'm using Selenium but I think I'm using it incorrectly. This is my web scraper so far

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PATH = "/Users/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://sa.ucla.edu/ro/Public/SOC/Results?t=19F&sBy=subject&sName=Computer+Science+%28COM+SCI%29&subj=COM+SCI&crsCatlg=Enter+a+Catalog+Number+or+Class+Title+%28Optional%29&catlg=&cls_no=&btnIsInIndex=btn_inIndex")
page_source = driver.page_source


# Click to open all of the class title links 
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Expand All Classes")
link.click()


# Passing data to beautifulsoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')

# Retrieving course titles
class_name=[] # List where class names are stored
# create a loop that runs through all <div> elements
for row in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'row-fluid class-title'}):
    class_name.append(row.text.strip('\n '))
print(class_name)
```

The details are stored here:

[image]

and the last code I tried was this but I came back with an empty list. I'm not sure if the list method would work here:

```
 # Trying to retrieve course details
    class_details=[] # List where class details are stored
    # create a loop that runs through all <div> elements
    for row in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'row-fluid header-row class-info'}):
        class_details.append(row.text.strip('\n '))
    print(class_details)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing incorrect class on your course details. here's the script for printing what you needed, course title and time and day. No need for beautifulsoup

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://sa.ucla.edu/ro/Public/SOC/Results?t=19F&sBy=subject&sName=Computer+Science+%28COM+SCI%29&subj=COM+SCI&crsCatlg=Enter+a+Catalog+Number+or+Class+Title+%28Optional%29&catlg=&cls_no=&btnIsInIndex=btn_inIndex")

# Click to open all of the class title links 
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Expand All Classes")
link.click()

course_name=[] # List where class names are stored
#find all course titles and print list
courseTitleElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='head']")
for courseTitleElem in courseTitleElems:
    courseTitle = courseTitleElem.text
    course_name.append(courseTitle)
    timeElems = courseTitleElem.find_elements_by_xpath("following-sibling::div/div[contains(@id,'children')]//div[contains(@class,'timeColumn')]")
    print("\n" + courseTitle)
    for timeElem in timeElems:
        timeColumn = timeElem.get_attribute("textContent").strip("\n")
        print("\n" + timeColumn)

#print list
print(course_name)
```

and here's print result
[image]